# Ubuntu 18 Server GRE tunnel with netplan?

Tags: networking, tunnel, netplan

How do I create a GRE tunnel with netplan? Previously in /etc/network/interfaces, I would do..

```
iface gr0 inet manual
  pre-up ip tunnel add gr0 mode gre remote 10.10.10.10 local 10.20.10.10 dev ens33 ttl 255
  post-down ip tunnel del gre0
```

How does this translate to netplan?

Comment: I don't think netplan supports GRE tunnels yet. However, I'm interested in a more authoritative answer on this question, as well.

Answer (score 0):

looks like this is an old question, but did some digging, and found the following:

- [Tunnels in NetPlan](https://netplan.io/examples#connecting-an-ip-tunnel): Example shows SIT tunnel, but changing to GRE *should* work...
- [Properties for the Tunnel Section of netplan](https://netplan.io/reference#properties-for-device-type-tunnels): yea, GRE is an option there.

I have now successfully tried this and it works... The TTL part i have not gotten working, but everything else does...